# Why are the values always rounded when numpy arrays are involved?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is the code I use as part of a numerical method in Python, but the problem arises when `B[n]` is calculated and it is a decimal. For example, if the answer of `B[n] - f * B[n-1]` is `-2.6`, `B[n]` becomes `-2` instead. And when I execute this exact command `(B[n] - f * B[n-1])` on the `print` command, it outputs `-2.6`.

This is ridiculous, why is this happening? Does the `numpy` array of `B` not accept decimals as its elements? If so, this is absolutely ludicrous in my opinion. BTW the `print` commands are there for me to see what was actually going on during the `for` loop and I outlined the findings above.

```
for n in range(1, nt):

    f = A[n, n-1] / A[n-1, n-1]

    A[n, n] = A[n, n] - f * A[n-1, n]

    A[n, n-1] = 0
    
    print(B[n], B[n-1], f,B[n] - f * B[n-1])
    B[n] = B[n] - f * B[n-1]
    
    print(A, B, f, B[n-1], B[n])
```

Comment: Sounds like you inadvertently defined your arrays to be integer, rather than floating-point; can you add how you define them to your question?

Comment: The most fundamental way to fix that would be to add something like `dtype=float` to the original definition (depending on what type you want). Often there are shortcuts that let you omit that, but sometimes you need to write it. It also lets you specify the type if a plain `float` doesn't have enough precision or otherwise doesn't suit.

Comment: @sabik: Integer arrays would not allow values like `2.6`.

Comment: Can you add enough to your code so that we can run it? As it is, we can't reproduce your problem, because you don't give the setup that gives rise to the problem...

Comment: Basically, if you could expand and cut down your code to make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: At a guess, though, `B` is an array of integer and `f` is a float; then `B[n] - f * B[n-1]` can be calculated as 2.6 but when it's assigned back to `B[n]`, it's converted into the array type, which is integer

Comment: how did you create `B`?

Comment: Sooner, rather than later, you need to learn that numpy arrays have a property called `dtype`.  Ignore that at your risk!

Comment: A = np.array([[1, 2, 0],
             [6, 2, 5],
             [0, 4, 14]])
    
    B = np.array([[5],
              [6],
              [7]])
    That is how I defined them

Comment: By the way, when i press Enter on the comment, it doesn't add a new line, it simply posts the comment. How tf do i go to a new line in this comment box???

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, questions need to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); something we can just paste into Python and it'll work, with no additional definitions.

For this problem, it might look something like this:

```
import numpy as np

B = np.array([1, 1])
f = 3.6
print(B[1] - f * B[0])  # prints out -2.6

B[1] = B[1] - f * B[0]
print(B[1])  # prints out -2; I was expecting -2.6
```

We can paste that into a file or a Jupyter notebook or the Python command-line and run it; no additional code (or guessing) required to see the problem happening.

Secondly, NumPy arrays (unlike most of the rest of Python) have a defined type; assigning to an individual element of an array converts the type. If we don't specify the type, NumPy tries to guess based on the data; usually that's satisfactory, but occasionally it guesses wrong. Here, because both of the initial values in `B` are integers, it guesses that we want `B` to contain the integer type.

Two ways to solve it:

- Help it guess right: `B = np.array([1.0, 1.0])`

  This is quick and easy and portable across contexts, libraries or even programming languages; it'll work anywhere, without having to look up how to specify the type.
- Tell it what we want: `B = np.array([1, 1], dtype=float)`

  This is the only way if the data is coming from elsewhere in the program and we can't change it easily; if we're particular about the type, for instance if we want more (or less) precision; or if we're using a function like `np.zeros` which doesn't take any data from which to guess.